# How to create custom and see output of custom inputs of a trained model?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I would like to evaluate tensorflow model on custom inputs, how to do so?
I have the following working tensorflow code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

all_data, all_labels = np.resize(np.linspace(0,50,100),[1000,3]), np.random.randint(0,2,[1000])
def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[len(all_data[0])]),
        Dense(20, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[20]),
        Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    ])
    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
        metrics=[
            tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy')
    
        ]
    )

    return model

model = build_model()
history = model.fit(all_data, all_labels, epochs=200)
```

I would like to give custom inputs to model, how to do so, for example an input like `[100,2,4]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [model.evaluate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate) which "Returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode."

It runs in batch mode, so if you pass a batch of inputs, it will compute the metrics, loss etc.

If you want the model to predict, the equivalent function is `model.predict(myinput)` which returns the predicted labels of your model on `myinput`.